# put two concatenatend var in a command - shell bash

Tags: string, variables, syntax, find

i have a problem with a script. i have the follow script:

```
while read line; do

    IFS=' '                                                         
                                                                    #sostituisco in IFS il carattere di default con quello di spazio
    i=0
    for campo in $line; do
        (( i++ ))
        if [[ $i -eq 1 ]] ; then                                    
            nome="$campo"
        elif [[ $i -eq 2 ]] ; then                                   
            cognome="$campo"
        fi
    done
    nome_file=$nome\_$cognome                                       
    echo $nome_file 
    j=$(find /home/ubuntu/Scrivania/Contatti -name 'nome_file*' | wc -l)
    echo $j     

done < $RUBRICA
```

the file RUBRICA contains rows like that:

```
andrea bargnani 6956959388 2632634643 2012/05/19

chris bosh 87654323234 78675432334 2014/06/16

zlatan ibrahimovic 2937485929 1938472639 2003/06/30

andrea mantovani 3402948586 0459687124 2015/01/25

andrea mantovani 3476589456 0451234567 2016/07/05

andrea mantovani 3478765434 67654334567 2011/09/10

marco polo 735636 36546456 2011/09/10
```

it take a file RUBRICA in input and for each line save in a var nome the firs column and in a second var cognome the second column. so, for the first row i'll have

```
nome=andrea
cognome=bargnani
```

after the for loop, the script concatenate the two var with an underscore in a new var called nome_file. then i use this var (nome_file) in a command. the problem is that i dont know how to put this var in the command. what is the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `$nome_file` like this:

```
j=$(find /home/ubuntu/Scrivania/Contatti -name "$nome_file*" | wc -l)
```

...but the for loop will be slow if there are many lines in $RUBRICA.

instead, use `awk`, e.g.:

```
awk '{printf "%s_%s\n", $1, $2}' $RUBRICA | while read nome_file; do
    echo $nome_file
    j=$(find /home/ubuntu/Scrivania/Contatti -name 'nome_file*' | wc -l)
    echo $j     
done
```

Comment: i try your first command. it works perfectly, thanks you are a genius. now i try the second

Comment: i try even your second advice and the terminal call me thi error:

awk: line 1: runaway string constant "%s_%s\n, $ ...

Comment: oops, typo. i left out the closing `"`. fixed.